# Is it possible to setup ElasticSearch and Grafana on a Service Fabric node?

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-service-fabric, grafana

Is it possible to deploy an application with both Grafana and ElasticSearch using service fabric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can run them in [containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers-linux)

On a [Linux based cluster](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-service-fabric-on-linux/):

- how to for [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)
- how to for [grafana](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/windows/)

Elasticsearch on windows:

- how to for [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/67)
- there is [windows support](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/windows/) for grafana, but I haven't found a docker file. So you'd have to create that

Comment: Is it possible in Windows?

Comment: added more info to answer, hope that helps

Comment: @LoekD Does Docker container work with Docker CE on Win10 in SF?

Comment: I don't think so. There are rumors about native support: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-containers/issues/2

Comment: @LoekD do you have an example of the service manifest used for the grafana container? I'm struggling to figure out how to pass in the command line arguments as I'm running behing Traefik, so need to enable the Serve_From_Sub_Path flag